# Gamecenter Matchmaking

Tags: ios8, game-center, gkmatchmaker

I need to match 3 players, 1 wizard and 2 warriors as attributes. How can that be done with GKMatch? The following snippet is from my code

```
    var wizard = true       
    enum Role : UInt32 {
            case wizard = 0xffff0000
            case warrior = 0x0000ffff
        }

    let matchRequest = GKMatchRequest()
        matchRequest.minPlayers = 3
        matchRequest.maxPlayers = 3
        matchRequest.playerAttributes = wizard ? Role.wizard.rawValue : Role.warrior.rawValue

   let matchMakerViewController = GKMatchmakerViewController(matchRequest: matchRequest)
        matchMakerViewController.matchmakerDelegate = self
        presentingViewController?.presentViewController(matchMakerViewController, animated: false, completion:nil)
```

Setting everything for two players, 1 wizard and 1 warrior, works fine but I need 2 warriors for a match.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Can you define 3 roles? Such as:

```
case wizard   = 0xffff0000
case warrior1 = 0x0000ff00
case warrior2 = 0x000000ff
```

You would need some slight differentiation between the two warrior types ("red" warrior and "blue" warrior), or maybe randomly assign type1 or type2 to each warrior player.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this will not work for my case since both warriors in the game are completely equal.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. The solution is to set warrior to 0xfffffff